# I want U1 to delay before uploading files

Tags: sync, files

I'm an author and I am often working on quite large book files, say around 15Meg, in LibreOffice.

LibreOffice autosaves every few minutes, and I manually save too. When I'm producing graphics or PDFs, I might be creating new files and overwriting old ones more than once per minute as I find errors and then overwrite the old files. No, the answer isn't to only produce a PDF only once, because many errors only become apparent when you convert the ODT to a PDF and view the result. So I might create the 'same' PDF a dozen times before I'm happy with it. The same happens when I am creating PNG files from Inkscape.

U1 syncs immediately, so every time I save something, off it goes, uploading huge files over my mobile broadband connection and slowing my PC to a crawl. I end up having to disconnect U1. For me, U1 is a very handy file backup solution and an easy way to sync my desktop and laptop.

What I want is to be able to set the sync delay for U1. I don't want it to sync every time something changes, I want to, for example, have it sync every 30 minutes.

The only way I can think to do this now is have U1 work off a copy of my files that I rsync with a cron job every 30 minutes. But that means using double the disk space, which is ridiculous.

But it would be much nicer if U1 had a setting "number of minutes to wait before syncing a changed file".

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option is not to edit files inside of the Ubuntu One directory directly.

Edit them in another directory and just copy them to the Ubuntu One directory once you think that they should be synced.

There is no option to delay the upload of dirty files inside of the Ubuntu One directory.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just pause U1 sync while you are working, and when you stop your work you activate it again? It seems the easier thing to do...